# PHP - Object Loop Condition

Tags: php, loops, object

I have this object:

```
$boosts = array(
    "2x12" => 500,
    "2x24" => 800,
    "2x7d" => 4500,
    "3x12" => 700,
    "3x24" => 1300,
    "3x7d" => 6500
);
```

And then a variable: `$type = "2x12";`
What I want to do is check in a loop if the variable $type exists in $boosts. I tried a lot of codes but I couldn't get it.

```
foreach ($boosts as $savedTypes) {
    echo json_encode($savedTypes) . "|";
    if ($boosts[$type] === $type) {
        echo "VALID";
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_key_exists( $key, $arr )`?

Comment: Thanks @RamRaider but I wanted to do it with the foreach loop. I'll use Ram's answer but thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($boosts as $key=>$value) {  
   if ($key === $type) {
    echo "VALID";
   }
 }
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something you ought to be able to use `array_key_exists` in this instance

```
$boosts = array(
    "2x12" => 500,
    "2x24" => 800,
    "2x7d" => 4500,
    "3x12" => 700,
    "3x24" => 1300,
    "3x7d" => 6500
);
$type='2x12';
$valid=array_key_exists( $type, $boosts );
echo $valid ? 'VALID' : 'INVALID';
```